# How to stop "Rogue" Particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I have just finished making a particle simulation to make laser fire but occasionally a "rogue" particle gets out and goes of in a random direction as you can see here.[image]

How do I stop it doing that?

Comment: Try Un-Checking "Random" under Emit From > Verts.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately that didn't do anything. :/

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: My guess is it's your emitter geometry.  Check the emitter in edit mode, turn on view vert normals from the UI properties panel.

Answer (score 1):

Gun Turret -

[image]

Blend file - Gunturret.blend

Not to take from Batfinger's comment above, this has been a common albeit minor problem for myself when emitting lines as particles.  Thanks to your
question I sat down and think I've cracked it at least for the gun projectile situation.

[image]

When using the generic "Line" particle for gun projectiles, reducing the emitter's vertices to just 1,  forces the launched lines along the correct trajectory.    There are no strays.  (Blender Vers 2.77a)

The emitter must be parented to the gun barrel if it's to be aimed or moved about.

Halo effect -  Rendered with Blender Internal

[image]

If using "Halo" in the Material slot, (e,g, for a space cannon) the emitter should be moved at least one line length from the end of the barrel.  When it's too close, the halo effect looks as though the plasma bolt (?) is being emitted from the turret and not launched from inside the barrel.

Emitter Object -

Using an Emitter Object for projectiles, comes up against the problem of rotating those previously launched when the barrel is aimed elsewhere.  They continue on their own trajectory but are pointing the wrong way!  Great for comedy!

Details -

The Particle plus Material settings are too numerous to list here but if you use the same as in the attached Blend file, none should stray from their intended trajectory.

Be mindful of BatFinger's mention about vertice normals.  Your single vertice may well be pointing elsewhere, not in line with the cannon.

Comment: PS: to the above - Get into the emitter settings, open the Cache tab and untick "External Cache"   I have a habit of ticking that to reduce filesizes when a lot of particles are involved.

Comment: Hello there! That is really helpful. After trying your method I discovered it was to do with the vertex group, I believe I had accidentally selected a vert in the barrel that caused it to occasionally emit a laser(cylinder) in the direction of it's normal. Thanks for your help as I probably wouldn't have found it if you hadn't posted that!

Comment: Have upvoted @batFINGER's comment above. It sums  up the situation in a few words. Thanks also for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change at emission the end to for example 60, then it is going to stop at frame 60[image]

Comment: But I don't want the particles to be spawning every second. I'd like 60 particles to be spread out over 250 seconds.